# Grails doesn't log plugins

Tags: grails

I cannot make the standard logging mechanism work for plugins without the use of the @Slf4j or @CompileStatic annotations.

The main application's standard logging is functioning properly.

I can't figure out why it doesn't work without the annotation.

grailsVersion=4.1.1, groovyVersion=2.5.14

logbook.groovy is including the packages:

```
List<String> debug = [
        'grails.app',                   
        'foo',           // My application and some plugins
        'boo',           // only grails plugins
]
debug.each {
    logger(it, DEBUG, ['FILE'], false)
}
```